# Get a list of objects from DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am binding a list of objects to a `DataGridView` like the following

```
var list = new List<Value>();
list.Add(new Value() { Name = "test" });
list.Add(new Value() { Name = "second" });

dataGrid.DataSource = list;
```

After inserting, editing, deleting... how can I retrieve a `List<Value>` from the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gridview edits your existing list.

The `list` will reflect the current contents of the gridview.

Answer (score 3):

The DataSource property should contain those changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx